# Asp.net Client-Server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Hello i have a web api with individual user accounts that creates tokens and send them back to the client.
I created an mvc client in a separate project that gets this token from the web api using the following function.

```
    private async Task<Dictionary<string,string>> GetTokenAsync()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();

        var post = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"grant_type","password" },
            {"username","admin@admin.com" },
            {"password","Panagorn18!" }
        };

        var response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:55561/token", new FormUrlEncodedContent(post));
        //response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        var json = JObject.Parse(content);

        var tkn = json["access_token"].ToString();
        var ex = json["expires_in"];
        var exp = new DateTime();
        exp.AddSeconds((long)ex);
        var ms = exp.ToUniversalTime().Subtract(
            new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).TotalMilliseconds;
        var dic = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "token", tkn },
            { "expires", ms.ToString() }
        };
        return dic;
    }
```

Now my questions are:
1. Where i have to save this token?
2. How can i keep the user loged in for example 30 days?
3. How can i check if the token expired and logout the user in the mvc project?
4. What configuration i have to put at startup class at mvc project to use this tokens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
1. Where i have to save this token?
```

Server side: Session, Memory Cache, etc

Client side: cookie, localStorage, sessionStorage, etc

Others: maybe another cache server (Redis)

Database is also a good place to save

```
2. How can i keep the user logged in for example 30 days?
```

It's what **token expiry date** used for (check **`AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan`**)

```
3. How can i check if the token expired and logout the user?
```

A good way is implement your own `AuthenticationTokenProvider`, **deserialize the token** passed to server, **check the expiry date** and add the AccessTokenExpired to response header

Sample code:

```
// CustomAccessTokenProvider.cs
public class CustomAccessTokenProvider : AuthenticationTokenProvider
{
    public override void Receive(AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext context)
    {
        context.DeserializeTicket(context.Token);
        var expired = context.Ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc < DateTime.UtcNow;
        if(expired)
        {
            context.Response.Headers.Add("X-AccessTokenExpired", new string[] { "1" });
        }

        base.Receive(context);
    }
}

// Startup.cs
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AccessTokenProvider = new CustomAccessTokenProvider()
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain me more the Receive function how to use it, where and how to check the expiration?

Comment: @PanayiotisIrakleous: I updated my answer to include usage for CustomAccessTokenProvider

Comment: i put your code on the server side and when token is expired i see in the header the value. So now i have to make a request when the web app (mvc) start to check if the token has expired? and how to keep the user loged in with the expiration date from the token?